# python scipy curve fit not working

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a lognormal distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def pdf(x, mu, sigma):
    return (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))


x_axis = [5e5,1e6,2e6,5e6,6e6]
y_axis = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8]
curve_fit(pdf,x_axis,y_axis,maxfev=10000,)
```

This returns the following:

```
C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:604: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)
Out[66]: 
(array([ 1.,  1.]), array([[ inf,  inf],
        [ inf,  inf]]))
```

These results don't really seem like a great fit. I know there are only five datapoints but when I use solver in excel I get the parameters of 0.1536 and 3.1915, which isn't perfect, but it is much closer.

edit: trying this with a cdf

```
def cdf(x,mu,sigma):
    return sp.norm.cdf((np.log(x)-mu)/sigma)

curve_fit(cdf,x_axis,y_axis,)
```

this returns the same error as above

Answer (score 2):

Have you visualized the data?

The given values for `x_axis` and `y_axis` look like this:

[image: x- and y-data]

If you use the given `x_axis` values and your Excel solver values for `mu=0.1536` and `sigma=3.1915` and then visualize the `pdf` you get this:

[image: fit]

So I wonder what result you want to get?

Actually the data in the first picture does not really look like a Log-normal pdf, does it?

Comment: No it doesn't - but my question is how can I get python to reproduce a similar result. I'm not interested in how good the fit is at this stage.

Comment: The `curve_fit` method (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) can take a parameter `p0` to provide starting values for the fit parameters. If you just want a similar result you can try `p0=[0.1536, 3.1915]`.

Edit: Actually if you try it you'll get `In [39]: curve_fit(pdf,x_axis,y_axis,[0.1536, 3.1915])
Out[39]: 
(array([  1.52130172e-01,   1.62769369e+02]),
 array([[  6.04181760e+24,   7.43184344e+22],
        [  7.43184344e+22,   2.99493671e+21]]))`
So my guess is that the Excel fit is so wrong that it can't be reproduced by the scipy fit.

Comment: Right, but that defeats the purpose of trying to fit the curve. The initial parameters I gave to solver in excel is 1,1 just as the default is in curve_fit.

Comment: Yes, but if you make a completely wrong fit in Excel, how should Scipy be able to reproduce that behavior?

Edit: Another approach might be to scale the values down first. Optimization algorithms might not like huge values like yours. You can scale them back afterwards.

Comment: OK thanks, do you have any idea how I can fit the same data to a CDF?

Comment: Just take the definition of the CDF instead of the PDF. Or what do you mean?